# Get a ID from URL in another Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

my question its simple... See the code:

My autocomplete:

```
$("#produto").autocomplete({
    source: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search/' + $('#codigo_fabricante').val(),
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#produto").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#procura_produto').val(ui.item.id);
        preencherLinhaProduto(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

Other function that recieves codigo_fabricante:
My function in controller:

```
public function search() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    // Consultando pelo que o usuÃ¡rio estÃ¡ digitando
    $term = $this->request->query ['term'];
    //This way isn't working, I tried ['pass'][0] either. 
    $fabricante = $this->request->params['pass'];
    echo($fabricante);
    $this->loadModel ( 'ProcuraProdutoPedOnline' );
    $produtos = $this->ProcuraProdutoPedOnline->find ( 'all', array (
            'limit' => 20,
             'fields' => array (
                    'cd_cpl_tamanho',
                    'ds_produto'
            ),
            'conditions' => array (
                    'cd_fabricante' => "$fabricante",
                    'ds_produto LIKE' => '%' . mb_strtoupper ( $term ) . '%'
            )
));
```

I want to get the value of + $('#codigo_fabricante').val() on my function "search()" that $fabricante recieves... How can I do that ?

Comment: This does not look like the CakePHP I know.... should you try this? `source: '/pedidos/search' + $('#codigo_fabricante').val(),`

Comment: Probably he has `Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));` uncommented.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the argument **pass** (that you are retrieving in the server side) as a **query string** value in the URL that you are calling in the **JS** code:

```
'/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search?pass=' + $('#codigo_fabricante').val()
```

**JS**

```
$("#produto").autocomplete({
    source: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search?pass=' + $('#codigo_fabricante').val(),
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#produto").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#procura_produto').val(ui.item.id);
        preencherLinhaProduto(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that way and o got :
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search?pass=&term=tenis"

I guess the pass= is coming empty

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

Modify your autocomplete like so, simply add the / to the end of search

```
$("#produto").autocomplete({
    source: '/pedidoOnline/Pedidos/search/' + $('#codigo_fabricante').val(),
    minLength: 2,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $("#produto").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#procura_produto').val(ui.item.id);
        preencherLinhaProduto(ui.item.id);
    }
});
```

Doing so will add the value as a url parameter, rather than passing it via `$_GET`

And in the called method, it will be available as a parameter. Its the cake way.

```
public function search($term) {
//method code here, but $term is now accessible as a local variable
//to debug this to make sure its getting passed in, add the next line of code
debug($term);die;
}
```

Next, put the full URL path into your browser bar  and sou should get an output of the value you've passed. for example:
`localhost/pedidoOnline/Pedidos/search/somestringhere` 
should debug a result of `somestringhere`

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't work... Two errors:

Warning (2): Missing argument 1 for PedidosController::search() [APP\Controller\PedidosController.php, line 90]

Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP\Controller\PedidosController.php, line 104]

Comment: You're calling an incorrect URL `pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search/` The URL you are calling should be along the lines of  `pedidoOnline/Pedidos/search/myValueHere` in the format of `root/controller/method/paramater` Why is index.php there?

Comment: Look : GET localhost/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search/?term=tenis And my code: source:'/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search/'+$('#codigo_fabricante').val(), 

With this error :

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/search/?term=tenis"

Comment: You're not following conventions, so you can't pass nor reach the controller methods correctly. see my last comment about what the url should be, and how to access the parameter. also read the documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#controller-conventions

Comment: I'm following the convention, that's why I'm using the index.php/... And I have others functions like this, but getting an Ajax with $_REQUEST[' ']..

Comment: You don't include the index.php with cake conventions. I've updated my answer with the url you need listed as source, with some other debugging information to help you

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the help... And as I said, that's what I've got:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/pedidoOnline/Pedidos/search/?term=tenis"

I have other function that use :

            source: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/EstProdutoLinhas/search/'+$('#codigo_fabricante').val(),

 and works, that's why I don't get it.

Comment: `localhost/pedidoOnline/Pedidos/search/tenis` is what the URL should be. Post your controller code and the view that holds the js query

Comment: So in an other function `$('#codigo_fabricante').val()‌` returns `?term=tenis` ? That's why you got the  `Notice (8): Array to string conversion`

Comment: @MponosGeorge this term= it's what I'm searching on my Input, before the ?term=tenis, needs the ID from cod_fabricante, got it ?

I got this error:
Undefined variable: term ,  on the line 69 :
 
   69 ->  debug($term);die;

And this :

Missing argument 1 for PedidosController::search(),  on the line 68 :
 
68 ->    public function search($term) {